# Can I build Perl Script to import into Outlook?

Tags: perl, outlook

If I have a .bas file on a server is it possible to setup perl script import that file into outlook and build a macro button that connects to it?

Answer (score 2):

See [my example script](http://www.unur.com/comp/ppp/perl-win32-ole-outlook-ex1.html) which accesses your Outlook contacts and exports their email addresses.

So, in principle, it is possible. In practice, you are going to have to spend a lot of time in the *Object Browser* and figuring out which OLE objects and methods to use.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me the best place to go to learn more about the OLE objects/methods?

Comment: @chad See Microsoft's VBA documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814736.aspx